# Joining two lists of object optimization

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a way of optimizing my LINQ query.

Classes:

```
public class OffersObject
{
    public List<SingleFlight> Flights { get; set; }
    public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; } = new List<Offer>();
}

public class SingleFlight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarrierCode { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Offer
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    public List<ExtraOffer> ExtraOffers { get; set; } = new List<ExtraOffer>();
}

public class ExtraOffer
{
    public List<int> Flights { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Sample object:

```
var sampleObject = new OffersObject
        {
            Flights = new List<SingleFlight>
            {
                new SingleFlight
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    CarrierCode = "KL",
                    FlightNumber = "1"
                },
                new SingleFlight
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    CarrierCode = "KL",
                    FlightNumber = "2"
                }
            },
            Offers = new List<Offer>
            {
                new Offer
                {
                    ProfileId = 41,
                    ExtraOffers = new List<ExtraOffer>
                    {
                        new ExtraOffer
                        {
                            Flights = new List<int>{1},
                            Name = "TEST"
                        },
                        new ExtraOffer
                        {
                            Flights = new List<int>{2},
                            Name = "TEST"
                        },
                        new ExtraOffer
                        {
                            Flights = new List<int>{1,2},
                            Name = "TEST"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Goal of LINQ query:

List of:

```
{ int ProfileId, string CommercialName, List<string> fullFlightNumbers }
```

`FullFlightNumber` should by created by "Id association" of a flight. It is created like: `{CarrierCode} {FlightNumber}`

What I have so far (works correctly, but not the fastest way I guess):

```
var result = sampleObject.Offers
                         .SelectMany(x => x.ExtraOffers, 
                                     (a, b) => {
                                                  return new
                                                         {
                                                             ProfileId = a.ProfileId,
                                                             Name = b.Name,
                                                             FullFlightNumbers = b.Flights.Select(f => $"{sampleObject.Flights.FirstOrDefault(fl => fl.Id == f).CarrierCode} {sampleObject.Flights.First(fl => fl.Id == f).FlightNumber}").ToList()
                                                         };
                                            })
                         .ToList();
```

**Final note**

The part that looks wrong to me is:

```
.Select(f => $"{sampleObject.Flights.FirstOrDefault(fl => fl.Id == f)?.CarrierCode} {sampleObject.Flights.FirstOrDefault(fl => fl.Id == f)?.FlightNumber}").ToList()
```

I am basically looking for a way of "joining" those two lists of the `OffersObject` by Flight's Id.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there will only be a few flights defined in sampleObject.Flights, a sequential search using a numeric key is hard to beat.

However, if the number of flights times the number of offers is substantial (1000s or more), I would suggest loading the list of flights into a dictionary with Id as the key for efficient lookup.  Something like:

```
var flightLookup = sampleObject.Flights.ToDictionary(f => f.Id);
```

And then calculate your FullFlightNumbers as

```
FullFlightNumbers = b.Flights
    .Select(flightId => {
        flightLookup.TryGetValue(flightId, out SingleFlight flight);
        return $"{flight?.CarrierCode} {flight?.FlightNumber}";
    })
    .ToList()
```

`TryGetValue` above will quietly return a null value for flight if no match is found. If you know that a match will always be present, the lookup cold alternately be coded as:

```
        SingleFlight flight = flightLookup[flightId];
```

The above also uses a *statement lambda*. In short, lambda functions can have either expression or statement blocks as bodies. See the [C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest replacing the double `.FirstOrDefault()` approach with [`.IntersectBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-intersectby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-1)))). It is available in the System.Linq namespace, starting from **.NET 6**.

`.IntersectBy()` basically filters `sampleObject.Flights` by matching the flight ID for each flight in `sampleObject` with flight IDs in `ExtraOffers.Flights`.

In the code below, `fl => fl.Id` is the **key selector** for `sampleObject.Flights` (i.e. `fl` is a `SingleFlight`).

```csharp
var result = sampleObject.Offers
    .SelectMany(x => x.ExtraOffers, 
        (a, b) => {
            return new
            {
                ProfileId = a.ProfileId,
                Name = b.Name,
                FullFlightNumbers = sampleObject.Flights
                    .IntersectBy(b.Flights, fl => fl.Id)
                    .Select(fl => fl.FullFlightNumber) // alternative 1
                    //.Select(fl => $"{fl.CarrierCode} {fl.FlightNumber}") // alternative 2
                    .ToList()
            };
        })
    .ToList();
```

In my suggestion I have added the property `FullFlightNumber` to `SingleFlight` so that the Linq statement looks slightly cleaner:

```csharp
public class SingleFlight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarrierCode { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
    
    public string FullFlightNumber => $"{CarrierCode} {FlightNumber}";
}
```

If defining `SingleFlight.FullFlightNumber` is not possible/desirable for you, the second alternative in the code suggestion can be used instead.

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xNYPlO).